# Bootstrap 4 Create a Six column layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using a Bootstrap layout for my design and i am trying to make it into a

six column layout when i try to create six column layout it is not so good,

maybe someone can give me the correct structure and css. And the issue here

is when I try to add additional steps i.e step 4, step5 & step 6 it overlaps

with the other steps

Here is the code i use

```css
.how-it-works {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/oBA969e.png), url(https://i.imgur.com/DwQeMMg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
    background-position: bottom, center;
    padding: 90px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.how-it-works:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: -30px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ByfB10E.png);
    width: 150px;
    height: 51px;
    content: "";
}

.how-it-works .text-xs-center>h2 {
    color: #d8bea5;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.how-it-works-wrap h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.how-it-works-wrap>p {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.how-it-works-steps {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2.1rem;
}

.how-it-works .how-middle {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.how-it-works p.pay-info {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d8bea5;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.how-it-works h3 {
    color: #fff
}

.how-it-works p {
    color: #9c9da5;
}

.step .icon {
    position: relative;
    width: 86px;
    height: 86px;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    line-height: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.step .icon:before {
    content: attr(data-step);
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 38px;
    background-color: #f30;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Give You Glory", cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

.step .icon img,
.step .icon svg {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
}

.how-it-works .step-2 {
    padding-top: 20%
}

.col1:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: -21%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 185px;
    height: 34px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/lUjAjcL.png) no-repeat;
}

.col2:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: -16%;
    top: 11%;
    width: 175px;
    height: 34px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/gbwqu8Y.png) no-repeat;
}

.how-it-works-solution {
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}

@media (max-width: 543px) {
    .col1:after,
    .col2:after {
        display: none
    }
}

@media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col1:after,
    .col2:after {
        display: none
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col1:after,
    .col2:after {
        display: none
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .col1:after,
    .col2:after {
        right: -30%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="how-it-works">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-xs-center">
                    <h2>How We Work</h2>
                    <div class="row how-it-works-solution">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 how-it-works-steps white-txt col1">
                            <div class="how-it-works-wrap">
                                <div class="step step-1">
                                    <div class="icon" data-step="1">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 483 483" width="512" height="512">
                                            <g fill="#FFF">
                                                <path d="M467.006 177.92c-.055-1.573-.469-3.321-1.233-4.755L407.006 62.877V10.5c0-5.799-4.701-10.5-10.5-10.5h-310c-5.799 0-10.5 4.701-10.5 10.5v52.375L17.228 173.164a10.476 10.476 0 0 0-1.22 4.938h-.014V472.5c0 5.799 4.701 10.5 10.5 10.5h430.012c5.799 0 10.5-4.701 10.5-10.5V177.92zM282.379 76l18.007 91.602H182.583L200.445 76h81.934zm19.391 112.602c-4.964 29.003-30.096 51.143-60.281 51.143-30.173 0-55.295-22.139-60.258-51.143H301.77zm143.331 0c-4.96 29.003-30.075 51.143-60.237 51.143-30.185 0-55.317-22.139-60.281-51.143h120.518zm-123.314-21L303.78 76h86.423l48.81 91.602H321.787zM97.006 55V21h289v34h-289zm-4.198 21h86.243l-17.863 91.602h-117.2L92.808 76zm65.582 112.602c-5.028 28.475-30.113 50.19-60.229 50.19s-55.201-21.715-60.23-50.19H158.39zM300 462H183V306h117v156zm21 0V295.5c0-5.799-4.701-10.5-10.5-10.5h-138c-5.799 0-10.5 4.701-10.5 10.5V462H36.994V232.743a82.558 82.558 0 0 0 3.101 3.255c15.485 15.344 36.106 23.794 58.065 23.794s42.58-8.45 58.065-23.794a81.625 81.625 0 0 0 13.525-17.672c14.067 25.281 40.944 42.418 71.737 42.418 30.752 0 57.597-17.081 71.688-42.294 14.091 25.213 40.936 42.294 71.688 42.294 24.262 0 46.092-10.645 61.143-27.528V462H321z" />
                                                <path d="M202.494 386h22c5.799 0 10.5-4.701 10.5-10.5s-4.701-10.5-10.5-10.5h-22c-5.799 0-10.5 4.701-10.5 10.5s4.701 10.5 10.5 10.5z" /> </g>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Register</h3>
                                    <p>Register with your email</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 how-it-works-steps white-txt col2">
                            <div class="step step-2">
                                <div class="icon" data-step="2">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="512" viewbox="0 0 380.721 380.721">
                                        <g fill="#FFF">
                                            <path d="M58.727 281.236c.32-5.217.657-10.457 1.319-15.709 1.261-12.525 3.974-25.05 6.733-37.296a543.51 543.51 0 0 1 5.449-17.997c2.463-5.729 4.868-11.433 7.25-17.01 5.438-10.898 11.491-21.07 18.724-29.593 1.737-2.19 3.427-4.328 5.095-6.46 1.912-1.894 3.805-3.747 5.676-5.588 3.863-3.509 7.221-7.273 11.107-10.091 7.686-5.711 14.529-11.137 21.477-14.506 6.698-3.724 12.455-6.982 17.631-8.812 10.125-4.084 15.883-6.141 15.883-6.141s-4.915 3.893-13.502 10.207c-4.449 2.917-9.114 7.488-14.721 12.147-5.803 4.461-11.107 10.84-17.358 16.992-3.149 3.114-5.588 7.064-8.551 10.684-1.452 1.83-2.928 3.712-4.427 5.6a1225.858 1225.858 0 0 1-3.84 6.286c-5.537 8.208-9.673 17.858-13.995 27.664-1.748 5.1-3.566 10.283-5.391 15.534a371.593 371.593 0 0 1-4.16 16.476c-2.266 11.271-4.502 22.761-5.438 34.612-.68 4.287-1.022 8.633-1.383 12.979 94 .023 166.775.069 268.589.069.337-4.462.534-8.97.534-13.536 0-85.746-62.509-156.352-142.875-165.705 5.17-4.869 8.436-11.758 8.436-19.433-.023-14.692-11.921-26.612-26.631-26.612-14.715 0-26.652 11.92-26.652 26.642 0 7.668 3.265 14.558 8.464 19.426-80.396 9.353-142.869 79.96-142.869 165.706 0 4.543.168 9.027.5 13.467 9.935-.002 19.526-.002 28.926-.002zM0 291.135h380.721v33.59H0z" /> </g>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                                <h3>Search</h3>
                                <p>Use search in the page</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 how-it-works-steps white-txt col3">
                            <div class="step step-3">
                                <div class="icon" data-step="3">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="512" viewbox="0 0 612.001 612">
                                        <path d="M604.131 440.17h-19.12V333.237c0-12.512-3.776-24.787-10.78-35.173l-47.92-70.975a62.99 62.99 0 0 0-52.169-27.698h-74.28c-8.734 0-15.737 7.082-15.737 15.738v225.043h-121.65c11.567 9.992 19.514 23.92 21.796 39.658H412.53c4.563-31.238 31.475-55.396 63.972-55.396 32.498 0 59.33 24.158 63.895 55.396h63.735c4.328 0 7.869-3.541 7.869-7.869V448.04c-.001-4.327-3.541-7.87-7.87-7.87zM525.76 312.227h-98.044a7.842 7.842 0 0 1-7.868-7.869v-54.372c0-4.328 3.541-7.869 7.868-7.869h59.724c2.597 0 4.957 1.259 6.452 3.305l38.32 54.451c3.619 5.194-.079 12.354-6.452 12.354zM476.502 440.17c-27.068 0-48.943 21.953-48.943 49.021 0 26.99 21.875 48.943 48.943 48.943 26.989 0 48.943-21.953 48.943-48.943 0-27.066-21.954-49.021-48.943-49.021zm0 73.495c-13.535 0-24.472-11.016-24.472-24.471 0-13.535 10.937-24.473 24.472-24.473 13.533 0 24.472 10.938 24.472 24.473 0 13.455-10.938 24.471-24.472 24.471zM68.434 440.17c-4.328 0-7.869 3.543-7.869 7.869v23.922c0 4.328 3.541 7.869 7.869 7.869h87.971c2.282-15.738 10.229-29.666 21.718-39.658H68.434v-.002zm151.864 0c-26.989 0-48.943 21.953-48.943 49.021 0 26.99 21.954 48.943 48.943 48.943 27.068 0 48.943-21.953 48.943-48.943.001-27.066-21.874-49.021-48.943-49.021zm0 73.495c-13.534 0-24.471-11.016-24.471-24.471 0-13.535 10.937-24.473 24.471-24.473s24.472 10.938 24.472 24.473c0 13.455-10.938 24.471-24.472 24.471zm117.716-363.06h-91.198c4.485 13.298 6.846 27.54 6.846 42.255 0 74.28-60.431 134.711-134.711 134.711-13.535 0-26.675-2.045-39.029-5.744v86.949c0 4.328 3.541 7.869 7.869 7.869h265.96c4.329 0 7.869-3.541 7.869-7.869V174.211c-.001-13.062-10.545-23.606-23.606-23.606zM118.969 73.866C53.264 73.866 0 127.129 0 192.834s53.264 118.969 118.969 118.969 118.97-53.264 118.97-118.969-53.265-118.968-118.97-118.968zm0 210.864c-50.752 0-91.896-41.143-91.896-91.896s41.144-91.896 91.896-91.896c50.753 0 91.896 41.144 91.896 91.896 0 50.753-41.143 91.896-91.896 91.896zm35.097-72.488c-1.014 0-2.052-.131-3.082-.407L112.641 201.5a11.808 11.808 0 0 1-8.729-11.396v-59.015c0-6.516 5.287-11.803 11.803-11.803 6.516 0 11.803 5.287 11.803 11.803v49.971l29.614 7.983c6.294 1.698 10.02 8.177 8.322 14.469-1.421 5.264-6.185 8.73-11.388 8.73z" fill="#FFF" /> </svg>
                                </div>
                                <h3>Checkout</h3>
                                <p>Pay now at the checkout</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p class="pay-info">Simple steps to follow</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 6 columns Responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377575/bootstrap-6-columns-responsive)

Answer (score 2):

First thing you gotta do is change col-md-4 to col-md-2.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 how-it-works-steps white-txt col3">
```

Bootstrap works off a 12 column grid so 12 / 2 = 6 columns

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/8594/

Edit:
Added in the arrows

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/8599/

Comment: I have changed the CSS to display the arrows using col1 class